# the eigenvector, eigenvalue of the matrix I-X(X^TX)^(-1)X^T

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$X=(x_1, ..., x_n)^T$$ denote any non-zero vector of length n and $$A=I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$$

(a) Show that X is an eigenvector of the matrix A.

(b) What is the eigenvalue associated with X?

(c) Show that any vector V that is orthogonal to X is also an eigenvector of A

(d) What are the eigenvalues of A?

I tried to show that X is an eigenvector of the matrix A (AX = λX).
$$AX = (I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)X \\ \quad= X-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TX \\ \quad= X-X(X^TX)^{-1}(X^TX) \\ = X-X = 0 $$
In this case, X is an eigenvector of A and λ=0 ?

(c) is similar to (a).
$$X^TV=0$$
$$AV = (I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)(X^TV)\\ 
 \quad = X^TV-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TX^TV\\
 \qquad = X^TV-(XX^{-1})((X^T)^{-1}X^T)X^TV\\
= X^TV-X^TV=0$$
In this case, V is an eigenvector of A and λ=0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers to (a) and (b) are correct. You've made a mistake with parts (c) and (d). Note that we have
\begin{align}
AV &= (I - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T) V = 
IV - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T
\\ & = 
V - X(X^TX)^{-1}\color{red}{(X^TV)} = V - 0 = V.
\end{align}
In this case, we see that $AV = 1\cdot V$, which is to say that $V$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated with $1$.